# How to get a parametrized collection with reflection by its type?

Tags: java

There is a simple class:

```
class Foo {
    private Set<Integer> one = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Long> two = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Double> three = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How can I write function `getSet` that returns me a collection by its type?

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Assert.assertEquals(foo.one, getSet(foo, Integer.class));
```

**Update**

I've write some prototype:

```
private static <T> Set<T> getSet(Object foo, Class<?> typeClass) {
    for (Field field : foo.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (field.getType() == Set.class) {
            if(/*how can I check that the set is parametrized?*/) { 
                return (Set<T>) Code.run(() -> field.get(foo));
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What shall I write in forth line to check the set is parametrized by `typeClass`?

Comment: What have you tried? If nothing, why? What have you found on google?

Comment: I've add some explanation

Comment: You should change `Class<?> typeClass` to `Class<T> typeClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0] == typeClass)
```

Comment: If a field is declared as a *raw* `Set`, the cast to `ParameterizedType` will fail. Use `instanceof` to guard against that.